# Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS in Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

It would be nice if Tornado Python requests to HTTP could automatically be redirected to HTTPS.

Is there any way to do this?

- Python 3v
- Tornado 3.1v

**Update**

New solution but... May i do something wrong (

http:// IP_ADDRESS :4443/

WARNING:tornado.general:SSL Error on 8 ('IP_ADDRESS', 51453): [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:547)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import http.server


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        if self.request.protocol == "http":
            self.redirect("https://%s" % self.request.full_url()[len("http://"):], permanent=True)

    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler),
])

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application,
    ssl_options = {
    "certfile": os.path.join("/var/pyTest/keys/", "cert.pem"),
    "keyfile": os.path.join("/var/pyTest/keys/", "key.pem"),
    }
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server.listen(4443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: I think there should be two server instances Listening on two different ports for http and https

Answer (score 5):

Your solution looks fine for a basic deployment.

If you're using an AWS load balancer and your certificate is installed on the load balancer, you need to check the [`X-Forwarded-Proto`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html) header.

```
def prepare(self):
    if ('X-Forwarded-Proto' in self.request.headers and
            self.request.headers['X-Forwarded-Proto'] != 'https'):
        self.redirect(re.sub(r'^([^:]+)', 'https', self.request.full_url()))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create another server instance that listens to port 80. Here is the modified version of your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def prepare(self):
        if self.request.protocol == 'http':
            self.redirect('https://' + self.request.host, permanent=False)

    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', MainHandler)
    ])
    application.listen(80)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(
        application, 
        ssl_options = {
            "certfile": os.path.join("/var/pyTest/keys/", "cert.pem"),
            "keyfile": os.path.join("/var/pyTest/keys/", "key.pem"),
        }
    )
    http_server.listen(443)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return a redirect code (TODO: lookup) or possibly a redirect page, JS, whatever you decide is a good idea. The point is that if a client (browser) comes in over http, you need to serve http. Then persuade the client to connect to a https (SSL) port instead. You can't do the redirecting on the server by itself.

You will indeed need two ports listening, one with SSL (https) for your content and one without (http) that will serve the redirect. I haven't tried doing this with Tornado, so I can't comment on details yet.

To the latter part and error message:

Connecting with http:// to a port expecting HTTPS will give SSL errors. Try using https:// in your client. Make sure http:// URLs point to ports not serving https and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

*WARNING:tornado.general:SSL Error on 8 ('IP_ADDRESS', 51453): [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:547)*

is what you get if you try to acess a http**s** content with a http url, for example:
htt**p**:// IP_ADDRESS :4443/

http**s**:// IP_ADDRESS :4443/ shall get you to the page(or next bug :/ ).
the rest is already explained by our colegues in the thread.
listen to some other port without ssl options set preferably 80 for http. and then redirect as you did with prepare.

for example...

```
def prepare(self):
    porthttp = "8889"
    porthttps = "8443"
    if self.request.protocol == 'http':
        self.redirect('https://' + self.request.host.replace(":"+porthttp,":"+porthttps))
```

and

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
ssl_opt = {
    'certfile': 'host.crt',
    'keyfile': 'host.key',
}
application.listen(8443,ssl_options= ssl_opt) 
application.listen(8889)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

that last code just as an example. set any application.listen(port) before the loop start.

Answer (score 0):

your route should be : (**r'/.*'**, MainHandler)